# Access MongoDB via HTTPS

Tags: mongodb, http, https

I woud like to connect to a MongoDB instance via HTTPS to access my MongoDB inside an Openshift/Kubernetes cluster.

The usage woud be

1. Connect with MongoDB Compass for administration.
2. Connect with a Java application which runns outside of the Openshift cluster.

The openshift cluster runs on a private cloud. I don't have permissions to open any SSH connection nor do any kind of port forwarding. Everything is restricted to HTTPS.

I learned allready, that adding an Openshift Route does not help and leeds to the *It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port* error message.

I noticed, that I can access Mongo Atlas instances with the `mongodb+srv://cluster0.example.mongodb.net` URI format. Is there a way to access my own MongoDB instance like this.

Or just any other idea to get access via HTTPS?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You would need to deploy your own web interface or have a look at https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express or https://github.com/SamuelTallet/MongoDB-PHP-GUI

Comment: MongoDB Compass connects directly, i.e. uses port 27017. How can you connect if the server allows only HTTPS? Connections to MongoDB can also be protected by SSL/TLS. In worst case, configure the MongoDB to listen to port 443, it works without any problem (but you may have to start the mongod service as root - which would be a decrease in security, but if the cloud provider is not smart enough....)